# Keyboard Expression Question Similar To (echo -ne '\015')

Tags: linux, cron, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I express (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>) to detach safely from a `screen` session in the same fashion as I would enter the key combination with my keyboard in the following fashion:

```
(echo -ne '\015')
```

I want to put these expressions into a script of some sort, is there a Linux keyboard key expression mappy out there or something like that?

Comment: Do you need this to run locally within an `X` session or should it also work remotely(ssh) or in a terminal/tty?

Comment: Hello @rudib I only need it to run locally in this case, I would like to script something that opens a screen, runs the command in the screen and then detaches itself. I have been creating a detached screen and running the command with the enter expression shown above in that detached screen && mailing myself a completion message and exiting the screen session as oppose to detaching. So I thought I could use key expressions to jiggarig it to function. I am still learning so its a trial and error process.

Comment: So do you need the script to wait or interact with it? Because if not, you can start the script detached in the first place. See my answer, I mentionened that. Or could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a command you can execute on a shell *within* a `screen` session to detach your terminal from that session.  `screen` is looking only at input *from your terminal* for the magic metacharacter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>), not at anything displayed within the terminal session managed by `screen` *itself*.  To demonstrate, I have created a file called `detachsequence` which contains a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> character followed by a `d` character:

```
$ hexdump detachsequence
0000000 01 64
```

If I `cat` this inside a `screen` session, nothing (remarkable) will happen; the file will simply be displayed (notwithstanding the invisible control character):

```
$ cat detachsequence
d
```

An `echo` or `printf` would be similarly unremarkable.

In point of fact, it would be a particularly bad security flaw if `cat`ting a file within `screen` could send control sequences to `screen` itself.

Comment: Yes, however it would be possible to launch the script detached in the first place `screen -d -m /the/script`. But this couldn't help detaching the "current" session.

Comment: That's interesting, I am using the method specified by @rudib and exit screen on completion. What If i was to add something in to say pass the detach command from the shell into the screen, this way it would be input? This is what I was hoping to do but I dont know how to express the keys ctrl + a + d to pass it in. Hopefully not too confusing. I couldn't find anything within screen manpage I could leverage but If I could cave-man my input into the cron by expressing the individual pressing of keys on my keyboard maybe that would work. Still learning this side. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**An universal solution could be:**

```
screen -d $STY
```

Screen will pass the session name to the `$STY` variable and then you can use `screen -d` with that.

You will probably want to run a command while detached, that can be done like that:

```
screen -d $STY & yourcommand
```

**Note:** `screen -d` is sufficient by itself. You don't need to specify `$STY`.

**You could also start a script that is detached in the first place instead:**

```
screen -d -m /the/script
```

But this would have the caveat that you won't have a time frame in which you can interact with the script until it is detached. If you need that, the former solution should be the way to go.

**Other solution (that depends on the environment):**

If you using the script on a virtual terminal within an `X` seesion, you can utilize `xdotool` to send the control sequence to the terminal:

```
xdotool key control+a+d
```

Comment: This will only work if you are in an X environment.

Comment: Indeed. It's probably not doable outside of that. But we don't know the exact environment yet.

Comment: "This" in the previous comment by @DopeGhoti refers to the `xdotool` solution. `screen -d` should work in an SSH session (no X server involved), for example. (The `$STY` argument may not even be needed)

Comment: @Kusalananda it's not needed, see my note. However you could also access other screens by providing a different variable. Both work here. I'm considering to remove the `$STY` in the main part of the answer, for simplicity. But I'm not sure if either version of the command is universally supported.

Comment: In my defense, my comment was written when the only solution in the answer _was_ the `xdotool` suggestion. (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think you can safely remove `$STY` as the question is about the equivalent of the keyboard shortcut that detaches the _current_ `screen` session. If you want to make it more universal, you'd have to dig up the change log to see what versions support what. The 4.00.03 version definitely supports `screen -d` to detach the current session.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I also now just realised you did not write this answer. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `Ctrl-<letter>` keypresses send characters codes 1 to 26 for the letters `A` to `Z`. That is, <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> or `^A` is sends the character 1, or `\x01` or `\001`, `^B` is 2, etc. The carriage return is `\015` or 13 (decimal) or `^M`.

So, `Ctrl-A d` would be `\001d`.

However, if you want to send that sequence as something `screen` would interpret, it's not that easy to do it from inside the screen itself. (You could do it from the terminal *outside* of `screen`.)

An easier way to ask `screen` to detach from a script is to run `screen -X detach`, possibly also using `-S` to specify which screen you want to detach and using the `STY` environment variable to find the identity of the current screen.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need. So I can run my command and send input to the screen so long as i reference the correct STY environment? Do you have any links that will describe the character codes or a manpage? Thanks